# Find value from json in js

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a value from json by using the JSON.parse function. My JSON is below:

```
var ralList = `{ 
    "RAL 1000": "205-186-136",
    "RAL 1001": "208-176-132",
    "RAL 1002": "210-170-109",
    "RAL 1003": "249-169-0",
    "RAL 1004": "228-158-0",
    "RAL 1005": "203-143-0",
    "RAL 1006": "225-144-0",
    "RAL 1007": "232-140-0",
    "RAL 1011": "175-128-80",
    "RAL 1012": "221-175-40",
    "RAL 1013": "227-217-199",
    "RAL 1014": "221-196-155",
    "RAL 1015": "230-210-181"
}`;

const data = JSON.parse(ralList);
```

How do I find the RGB value according to RAL xxxx in data object?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `data["RAL xxxx"]`?

Comment: Really simple, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to access the property with this syntax:

```js
console.log(data["RAL 1000"]);
```

Or with a for loop to do it dynamically:

```js
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(data[key]);
}
```